# Change default skin on spawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a server. I'd like new players haven't Steve skin as default. I'd like all new players spawn with specific skin (that I chose). How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't change another player's skin.

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible. Only the player can change their own skin, this cannot be done by a server, and not even prompted by a server. You can add a request at spawn for them to do this though.